# Access - Enabling macros causes Access to crash

Tags: macros, crash, office-2007

I have a database embedded with VBA code.  Database has been running for years and then, all of a sudden when I open the form which contains the bulk of VBA code, access crashes.

Here is the catch, I copied the database to another computer with access and the database opens and operates no problem (VBA code works).  I figured out it was related to macros by then moving the database back under a differenct name and opening it, got the warning that macros were disabled.  As soon as I enable access crashes.  ???

Access version on both machines is 2007
Computer which crashes access is Win 10
Computer that runs the database no problem Win XP

Any thoughts